# Checking that the query string has not changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have the following code to check that a query string has not changed:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                Label_Error.Visible = false;
                string query_string = Request.QueryString["GUID"].ToString();
                Session["GUID"] = query_string;
            }

            else
            {
                string GUID = "";

                try
                {
                    GUID = Session["GUID"].ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Session.Abandon();
                    Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
                    return;
                }

                if (GUID.Equals(Request.QueryString["GUID"].ToString()) == false)
                {
                    Session.Abandon();
                    Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, I have this code in a button-click event handler to check that the value of the query string has not changed (again):

```
protected void ImageButton_LogIn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Validation val = new Validation();

            string GUID = "";
            string query_string = "";

            try
            {
                GUID = Session["GUID"].ToString();
                query_string = Request.QueryString["GUID"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
                return;
            }

            if (val.EmptyString(GUID) == true || val.checkTransactionGUIDExists(GUID) == false || GUID.Equals(query_string) == false)
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
            }
```

Now, the problems are two:

1) if I change the query string in the URL and click on the button, the user is not redirected to the error page.

2) if I change the query string in the URL and hit enter in the address bar, the user is not redirected to the error page.

What I want basically is that, when the user is redirected to the web page, it saves the query string into a session.  If the user changes the value of the query string in the address bar, and either pressed enter in the address bar or presses my button, he is redirected to the error page.

However, my code is failing.  Can anyone help please?  Thanks :)

Comment: Have you used the debugger to step through the code and see which conditional logic is or is not happening?

Comment: Thanks :)  I am debugging the program right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this instead?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Always get the query string no matter how the user go to this page
    string query_string = Request.QueryString["GUID"].ToString();

    // Only store the query string in Session if there is nothing in Session for it
    if(null == Session["GUID"])
    {
        Session["GUID"] = query_string;
    }

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        Label_Error.Visible = false;
    }

    // Always check to see if the query string value matches what is in Session
    string GUID = "";
    try
    {
        GUID = Session["GUID"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
        return;
    }

    if (GUID.Equals(Request.QueryString["GUID"].ToString()) == false)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
    }
```

This should solve your problem of the `Session` value being overwritten when a query string is put into the address bar and enter is pressed by the user.

Comment: Yeah I think is the only way.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  I will try it out and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is that `Response.Redirect` needs the `false` at the final of the sentence like `Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm", false);` becouse that you have it inside the try cath the error will be throw.

I hope that help you.

Comment: Just to clarify what Freak_Droid is recommending, the extra `false` parameter to the `Response.Redirect()` stops a `ThreadAbortException` from happening, because is ending the `Response` object.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem has not been solved completely.  I changed the address in the address bar, hit enter and it is entering the !isPostBack block, thus bypassing my checks.  It seems that changing the address and hitting enter does not constitute a postback.  How can I detect this situation then, that is, when the user changes the address and hits enter in the address bar?